# Get a list of tasks which are assigned but not claimed?

Tags: activiti

Using activiti-rest 5.16.4, is it possible to `GET runtime/tasks` a list of tasks which are assigned but not claimed?

Or do i have to filter on `GET history/historic-task-instances` result set?

Comment: By "assigned", you mean tasks that have a _candidate_ user and/or group, but no assignee, right ?

Do you have a "current user" to which the query apply ? If this is the case, then you can use "unclaimed=true&candidateUser=someone" as a query string.

Comment: No I mean tasks they have an assignee, but are not claimed (with `POST runtime/tasks/{taskId}` and `{"action": "claim", "assignee": "user"}`). Is there a way to get this done? Or is a set assignee equal to claimed?

Comment: My understanding is that, in Activiti, an assigned task has already been claimed. Check the docs for the "claim" method of the TaskService:

"Claim responsibility for a task: the given user is made assignee for the task. The difference with setAssignee(String, String) is that here a check is done if the task already has a user assigned to it. No check is done whether the user is known by the identity component."

In other words, when you call the "claim" method the task will make a transition from "unassigned" to "assigned".

Comment: Ok thanks, than we have to change some parts in the software.

Comment: Phillippe is correct, a task can be assigned in one of three ways.
1. An explicit assignment based on some rule set.
2. The task is claimed from a candidate list
3. The task is delegated

However, a task is not actually "assigned" until one of the above events takes place.

Comment: I´ll "promote" my comment to an answer. Any objections ?

Comment: @PhilippeSevestre no, no objections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that, in Activiti, an assigned task has already been claimed.

Check the docs for the "claim" method of the TaskService:

> "Claim responsibility for a task: the given user is made assignee for
>   the task. The difference with setAssignee(String, String) is that here
>   a check is done if the task already has a user assigned to it. No
>   check is done whether the user is known by the identity component."

In other words, when you call the "claim" method the task will make a transition from "unassigned" to "assigned".